# clear powershell session

Tags: powershell

Is there a commandlet that clears the current powershell session variables that I have added?

I am using the Add-Type commandlet, and I am getting the error "Cannot add type. The type name already exists."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't unload .NET assemblies that have been loaded into the default AppDomain which is what Add-Type does. You can rename types or namespaces to limp along but at some point you just have to exit and restart PowerShell.

This is not a PowerShell limitation so much as it is a .NET/CLR limitation.  You can load .NET assemblies into separate AppDomains which can be unloaded later but you would have to code that yourself and it imposes restrictions on the types you plan to use in the separate AppDomain.  That is, those types need to work through .NET Remoting so they either have to derive from MarshByRefObject or they have to be serializable (and this applies to all the objects referenced by their properties, and so on down the object graph).

Comment: There isn't a way to unload assemblies added via Add-Type.  You have to restart PowerShell.  You could load the assemblies via Add-Type and do some experimenting with those types using background jobs (Start-Job).  Each job spins up a new PowerShell instance which goes away when that job is complete.

Comment: But what if you have inline c# code in the script? It makes debugging the script painful

Answer (score 9):

A possible "work around": Open a powershell window and then to run your script enter `powershell .\yourScriptHere.ps1`

This launches a new powershell instance which exits when your script exits. If you want to "play" in the new instance then change the invocation to `powershell -NoExit .\yourScriptHere.ps1` and the new instance will not exit when the script completes. Enter `exit` when you need another restart and hit the "up arrow" key to get the previous command. All script output will appear in the same window. The overhead for starting a new powershell instance is low -- appears to be less than 1 second on my laptop.